# Creating a loop that plots a specific # of points[(x,y) & magnitude] based on user_input?

Tags: python

## I'm attempting to make a program that allows the user to make figures. [python3]

the program will first ask for how many points, then ask to plot the point (x, y) coordinates for each
then it should ask how many lines, and ask for user input for the (x,y) coordinates of the points (based on the number of lines) to connect.
THEN it has to restart and ask for another set of points/ and lines.

```
import program # I have a drawing program

while True: 
    print('enter points')
    points = int(input(''))

    for points in range(0, points):
        print('enter x')
        x = int(input(''))
        print('enter y')
        y = int(input(''))
        draw.point(x , y, size, size)  

        while (?) :              # this is where my issue is !!!!
            print('line')
            line = int(input(''))
            for line in range(line):
                x1 = int(input(''))  # these are the x,y coordinates for the
                x2 = int(input(''))  #     points to connect the lines
                x3 = int(input('')) 
                x4 = int(input('')) 
                Color('?')           #is there a way to cycle colors?
                draw.line(x1, x2, x3, x4)  

    if points <= 0:
        exit()
```

the issue is I need to plot all the points before asking for the lines, but I cannot figure out how to nest the loops. The output for this does not ask for the correct amount of points before jumping to the lines.

also, is there a way to cycle colors so that the loops cycle between 3 different colours, ie. figure one is blue, 2 is pink, 3 is orange, 4 is blue... etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you have multiple questions. Try focusing on one question per thread.
Now, I'll try to help for the whole package.

---

## 1. Is there a way to cycle between colors.

Yes, it is called using a list. You could do it creating a list of colors, such as :

```
my_colors = ['red', 'blue', 'yellow']
```

And pass the color you wish to draw to your draw function. I bet you're using `matplotlib` to draw. Changing the color in such a library is as simple as modifying the `color` parameter of a draw function (would it be a point, a line, a circle... you name it).

---

## 2. Can I plot all the points before asking for the lines.

Yes, you can. And good news, you don't need to do some `loop nesting`. You had the good logic earlier on. You asked for the user a number of points to draw, and set a condition on a for loop to draw these points. You could now do the same.

You might want to ask a new question :

```
print('enter number of lines:')
lines = int(input(''))
```

And then, make another `for` loop to draw these lines, such as before. Your code would look like this...

```
import program # I have a drawing program


color = ['red', 'blue', 'yellow']
while True:
    # You are seeking your number of points.
    print('enter points')
    points = int(input(''))

    # You are drawing your points.
    for points in range(0, points):
        print('enter x')
        x = int(input(''))
        print('enter y')
        y = int(input(''))
        draw.point(x , y, size, size)  

    # You are asking the number of lines.
    print('Enter number of lines...')
    lines = int(input(''))

    # You are drawing your lines the number of times wanted.
    for index in range(0, lines):
        x1 = int(input('x1:'))  # these are the x,y coordinates for the
        x2 = int(input('x2:'))  #     points to connect the lines
        y1 = int(input('y1:')) 
        y2 = int(input('y2:')) 
        draw.line(x1, x2, y1, y2, color[index % 3])

    if points <= 0:
        exit()
```

### Note :

I used `[index % 3]`. I invite you to study this behavior as it is going to be useful in your futur as a dev.